# Company merger scenario

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

How do I design a technical strategy for the merging of two companies allowing seamless sharing of imformation between the two companies?

Answer (score 1):

For DNS see [Example: Merging DNS Namespaces](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756792%28v=WS.10%29.aspx%22Example:%20Merging%20DNS%20Namespaces%22)

For active directory see [Active Directory Merger, Acquisition, and Divestiture: Restructuring Limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mergers_acquisitions_active_directory_prune_and_graft_restructuring_support_limitations%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

This is however the tip of the iceberg.  You need to also worry about email, application issues, permission sets etc.  This is a very broad question and I think you will be better able to ask a more specific question after reading those articles.